# How to pass TFS Build number as argument in PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a powershell script in Visual Studio Build, and I wanted to get the build number to be passed as argument.

Using the below arguments, this doesnt pass the build number but it passes as a literal word.

[image]

Please help in getting the build number to be passed as argument. Thank you in advance.

I'm using TFS 2015.

Answer (score 5):

I have already solved this issue. I created a new variable in the variables tab and pass the value of the build number.

[image]

And then I set it as an argument in the PowerShell script.

[image]

This solves my problem :)